# Что такое фантомный тип и как это связано с traits?

Tags: scala, traits, дизайн-языка, теория-типов

Много раз натыкался на термин «фантомный тип», особенно в контексте обсуждения *traits* в языке Scala.

Что это такое? При чём здесь *traits*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Заранее прошу извинить за длину ответа, просто иначе понять, что такое фантомные типы и как они используются, будет трудно, а тема и правда интересная.

Предположим, "Роскосмос" попросил написать нас систему управления запуском ракет. "Ракета должна быть заправлена топливом и кислородом, и только после этого можно запускать", - лаконично констатирует техническое задание. Не долго думая, мы пишем следующий код на языке [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) (в функциональном стиле, не в объектно-ориентированном, почему - будет видно впоследствии):

```
object UnsafeRocketModule {
  case class Rocket private[UnsafeRocketModule] (hasFuel: Boolean, hasO2: Boolean)

  def createRocket() = Rocket(false, false)
  def addFuel(r: Rocket) = Rocket(true, r.hasO2)
  def addO2(r: Rocket) = Rocket(r.hasFuel, true)
  def launch(r: Rocket) = 
    if (!r.hasFuel || !r.hasO2)
      throw new Exception("Попытка запустить неподготовленную ракету!")
    else
      println("3-2-1... Пуск!")
}
```

Модуль UnsafeRocketModule определяет тип Rocket, функцию-конструктор ракет (т.к. конструктор типа Rocket не экспортируется модулем в целях поддержания инкапсуляции), а также функции заправки ракеты топливом, кислородом, и функцию запуска ракеты. Мы также отслеживаем состояние ракеты (заправленность топливом и кислородом) и генерируем исключение при попытке запустить неподготовленную ракету. Загрузим этот модуль в Scala REPL, а затем попробуем ввести определение функции, которая подготавливает ракету (заправляет топливом и кислородом), и запускает ее:

```
scala> def prepareAndLaunchRocket() {
     |   import UnsafeRocketModule._
     |   launch(addFuel(createRocket()))
     | }
prepareAndLaunchRocket: ()Unit
```

Все скомпилировалось без ошибок, можно работать:

```
scala> prepareAndLaunchRocket()
java.lang.Exception: Попытка запустить неподготовленную ракету!
    at UnsafeRocketModule$.launch(<console>:13)
    at $anonfun$prepareAndLaunchRocket$2.apply(<console>:8)
    at $anonfun$prepareAndLaunchRocket$2.apply(<console>:8)
        ... пропущено ...
```

Вот незадача: в тексте функции prepareAndLaunchRocket мы заправили ракету топливом, но забыли заправить кислородом! Эта типичная для программ ошибка: попытка выполнить операцию над объектом, который находится в неподходящем для этого состоянии. Этот класс ошибок выявляется **во время выполнения программы (run time)**, и очень часто, уже в процессе эксплуатации. Но мы ведь не хотим, чтобы из-за нашей программы взрывались ракеты, только потому, что в коде мы забыли подготовить ее должным образом, а из-за нехватки времени и внимания написали тесты, не покрывающие этот случай, что не позволило выявить проблему до сдачи в эксплуатацию. Поэтому, исправив функцию prepareAndLaunchRocket, мы понимаем, что пришло время что-то кардинально менять. А именно: мы должны придумать способ гарантировать, что перед запуском (то есть, вызовом функции launch()) ракета будет подготовлена должным образом, то есть будут вызваны обе функции addFuel И addO2. Такая гарантия означает, что попытка запуска неподготовленной ракеты должна теперь выявляться **во время компиляции (compile time) программы**! Иными словами, компилятор не должен нам позволить скомпилировать ошибочное определение prepareAndLaunchRocket, приведенное выше. А это означает, что это определение не должно пройти проверку типов. То есть, мы должны расширить систему типов, принятую в нашем языке программирования. С этого момента начинается магия.

Первое, что мы делаем, это переписываем определение типа Rocket следующим образом:

```
object SafeRocketModule {
  case class Rocket[Fuel, O2] private[SafeRocketModule] ()

  // ...
}
```

Что мы поменяли? Тип Rocket приобрел два параметра типа (Fuel и O2), а атрибуты hasFuel и hasO2 были изъяты. Мы перенесли отслеживание состояния заправленности ракеты топливом и кислородом из системы времени выполнения в систему типов, то есть в систему времени компиляции. То, что отслеживалось атрибутами класса отныне отслеживается параметрами этого типа. Теперь добавим следующие вспомогательные типы:

```
sealed trait NoFuel
sealed trait HasFuel
sealed trait NoO2
sealed trait HasO2
```

Эти типы будут использоваться нами как значения времени компиляции вместо значений времени выполнения (true и false для атрибутов hasFuel и hasO2) для индикации состояния заправленности ракеты. Это типы-маркеры, существующие только для подстройки системы типов, они не имеют атрибутов, а их значения (new NoFuel { ... }) нами никогда не будут использованы. **Такие типы называются фантомными**. А traits являются удобным механизмом их определения. С их помощью мы можем переписать оставшиеся функции модуля:

```
def createRocket() = Rocket[NoFuel, NoO2]()
def addFuel[O2](r: Rocket[NoFuel,O2]) = Rocket[HasFuel,O2]()
def addO2[Fuel](r: Rocket[Fuel,NoO2]) = Rocket[Fuel,HasO2]()
def launch(r: Rocket[HasFuel,HasO2]) = println("3-2-1... Пуск!")
```

Обратим внимание: потребности в проверке заправленности ракеты функцией launch() больше нет. Система типов гарантирует, что launch() будет вызвана только для корректно подготовленной ракеты. Кроме того, становится понятно, почему нам следует использовать функциональный стиль, а не объектно-ориентированный. В последнем случае объект Rocket был бы создан единственный раз и функции addFuel, addO2 и launch вызывались бы впоследствии как его методы. Нам же необходимо менять тип ракеты при вызове соответствующих операций, и создавать значения этих типов с нуля, что и предполагает функциональный стиль. Загрузим модуль SafeRocketModule в Scala REPL, а затем снова попробуем ввести ошибочное определение функции prepareAndLaunchRocket:

```
scala> def prepareAndLaunchRocket() {
     |   import SafeRocketModule._
     |   launch(addFuel(createRocket()))
     | }
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : SafeRocketModule.Rocket[SafeRocketModule.NoFuel,SafeRocketModule.NoO2]
 required: SafeRocketModule.Rocket[SafeRocketModule.NoFuel,SafeRocketModule.HasO2]
         launch(addFuel(createRocket()))
                                    ^
```

Компилятор не дал ошибочному определению попасть в код программы из-за ошибки во время проверки типов. Исправим определение функции:

```
scala> def prepareAndLaunchRocket() {
     |   import SafeRocketModule._
     |   launch(addFuel(addO2(createRocket())))
     | }
prepareAndLaunchRocket: ()Unit

scala> prepareAndLaunchRocket()
3-2-1... Пуск!
```

Компиляция прошла успешно, пробный запуск осуществлен без ошибок. Теперь в эксплуатацию попадет *гарантированно* корректная версия этой функции, *даже при отсутствии тестов* - верификацию выполнила за нас система типов. Наша новая реализация имеет также и другие преимущества, по сравнению со старой: расширенная нами система типов гарантирует, что ракета будет заправлена топливом и кислородом только один раз, не допуская повторных вызовов функций заправки для ракеты, которая уже была заправлена:

```
scala> addFuel(addFuel(createRocket))
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : SafeRocketModule.Rocket[SafeRocketModule.HasFuel,SafeRocketModule.NoO2]
 required: SafeRocketModule.Rocket[SafeRocketModule.NoFuel,?]
       addFuel(addFuel(createRocket))
                      ^

scala> addO2(addO2(createRocket))
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : SafeRocketModule.Rocket[SafeRocketModule.NoFuel,SafeRocketModule.HasO2]
 required: SafeRocketModule.Rocket[?,SafeRocketModule.NoO2]
       addO2(addO2(createRocket))
                  ^
```

Рассмотренный способ применения фантомных типов часто используется при проектировании публичных интерфейсов (API) в таких языках, как Haskell, особенно для сложных интерфейсов. В других языках, с менее развитой системой типов, эти приемы не используются вовсе. К примеру, в Java, насколько мне известно, все это не работает "из коробки", и надо делать уродливую "мумбу-юмбу", чтобы получить похожий результат. Также следует заметить, что это не единственная область применения фантомных типов. Более подробно о последних и о возможных областях применения можно почитать здесь (все источники англоязычные):

1. [Phantom Types In Haskell and Scala](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/10/phantom-types-in-haskell-and-scala.html). Пример с ракетами был адаптирован из этой статьи, где параллельно приводится версия на Haskell.
2. [Phantom type (HaskellWiki)](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type)
3. [A Foundation for Embedded Languages by Morten Rhiger](http://www.brics.dk/RS/02/34/) - основательная академическая публикация о фантомных типах и их применениях в Haskell

Comment: Хороший ответ, спасибо.

Comment: Можно ли сказать, что фантомные типы, это типы, экемпляры (instances) которых никогда не создаются, которые используются для других целей?

Comment: Да, верно. Более точно, это типы, которые 1) не имеют значений (в терминах ООП - instances); 2) используются для конструирования других типов. 2-ое свойство здесь самое важное: в конечном счете единственная цель, для которой мы создаем фантомные типы, - чтобы использовать их в качестве параметров каких-то параметризованных типов.

Comment: Спасибо, отличный ответ.